# Kernel 4.18.10 : firmware d102e_ucode.bin for driver e100 missing

Tags: linux-kernel, driver, firmware

My network adapter is an Intel 82551IT. I'm building the system with Buildroot.

I can modprobe e100, but ifup -a fails with the error : "Failed to load firmware e100/d102e_ucode.bin".

As a matter of fact, the file is not present on my system. So, how do I get it ?

Comment: Unlike to many other forums, on Stack Overflow we avoid: 1. A solution in the question itself and 2. A word "SOLVED" in the question's title. Instead, you may answer you own question and mark answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to select the linux-firmware package in Buildroot.

Then :

```
$ cp -r <BUILD_DIR>/linux-firwmare-<version>/e100 <OUTPUT>/target/lib/firmware
```

Comment: A patch, accepted by the buildroot team, now takes care of copying the files to the target directory : https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/1024035/